# Solution of Laplace equation for a homogeneous electric field and an uncharged conducting sphere

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, boundary-conditions

We consider an initially uncharged metal sphere of radius R surrounded by an external homogeneous electric field $\vec E = (0, 0, E) \vec e_z$.

We are advised to use the general Laplace solution  for a cylindrical symmetry. And as boundary conditions it was said to consider the potential in infinity and close to the sphere.

We use the general solution of Laplace eq. but for cylindrical symmetry, that means:

$$\phi(r,\theta)=\Sigma_{l=0}^{\infty}[A_lr^l+B_lr^{-(l+r)}]P_l(cos\theta)$$

1st BC: $\vec r\rightarrow \infty$

The electric field is constant. Then we can write $\Phi(\vec r)=-Ez + \Phi_0=-Ercos\theta + \Phi_0$

Then we use the general formula $\phi(\vec r)=A_0 + A_1r cos\theta + \Sigma_{l=2}^{\infty}$.

By comparing terms we can find $A_0$ and $A_1$.

I understand why we took into consideration the first two terms. Since our potential had two terms, and we wanted to have a similar expression.

2nd BC: $\phi(r=R,\theta)=constant$

Here we have: $\phi(r,\theta)=(A_0 + B_0r^{-1})P_0(cos\theta)+ (A_1r + B_1r^{-2})P_1(cos\theta) +\Sigma_{l=2}^{\infty}[A_lr^l+B_lr^{-(l+r)}]P_l(cos\theta)$

I don't understand, what is the reason that we considered the first two values of l, l=0,1 and not further more?

Comment: It's because the external field only has a $P_1(\cos\theta)$, so that's all you have to match. You could add more harmonics, but the coefficients would all be zero, so why bother?

Comment: Which external field? What do you mean that it has only $P_1cos \theta$ ?

Comment: Your statement say  "surrounded by an *external* homogeneous electric field"  You also say yourself on line 8 that "Then we can write  $\Phi({\bf r})=-E r P_1(\cos \theta)+ \Phi_0$".